# Cells disappearing from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am using  [GlyuckDataGrid](https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid) for multicolumn tables

This library does not support self-sizing cells.
To make it work with the dynamic width I am setting cell width based on the highest (longest) textLabel width using `sizeWithFont...` method.

```
//Assuming max width = 200

func dataGridView(_ dataGridView: DataGridView, widthForColumn column: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return dataSource.columnWidths[dataSource.header[column].key] ?? 0
 }

func dataGridView(_ dataGridView: DataGridView, heightForRow row: Int) -> CGFloat { 
    return dataSource.rows[row].max(by: {$1.height > $0.height})?.height ?? 0
}
```

For calculating height I am using max textLabel height for that particular row and applying it to each component of that row.

This works perfectly fine in most of the cases but sometimes the cells start disappearing randomly. It shows up again when I scroll up/down a bit.

I tried various solutions posted on community( http://ioscake.com/uicollectionviews-cell-disappearing.html ) and came to a conclusion that this can only happen if `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` returns wrong attributes.

In most cases it seems to happen only when the rows are more than 100..

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this.